# How to write a function as range?

Tags: python, function, range

I need to use a function as range but an error appears saying that n was not set: 
NameError: name 'n' is not defined

I'm actually learning how to use python and I do not know if the syntax is correct, I just find examples of lists as ranges.

Could someone clear my ideas, give me some suggestions?

[EDIT1] My function z depends on j and f(n).

[EDIT2] I´m usind fibonacci ranges for integrate over a sphere.

The program is something like this:

```
def f(n):
    a, b = 0, 1
    for i in range(n):
        a, b = b, a+b
    return a 

def y(n):
    return f(n) + some_const

def z(j):
    for j in range(0,f(n-1)):
        return j*y(n) + j*f(n-1) + j*f(n)
```

Comment: Where is `n` defined in `z()`?

Comment: what exactly do you want to do? As it stands right now, you're calling return inside a loop, so you exit on the first iteration.

Also, please don't just write `something` for your variables. If the value matters, give us the one you're using. If it doesn't, just pick one (0 would be a good one). You also never initialize `n`. It helps tremendously if your example code is actually valid code.

Comment: `return` in function z will only return the result of the first iteration, you should use yield instead

Comment: I think you meant to create a variable before your for loop, add the values in the for loop, then return the accumulated value at the end of the z(j) func ... along with defining variable 'n' somewhere

Comment: @PRMoureu Or `print`, which would be simpler. Note the OP said he was a beginner, so using `yield` would probably be confusing.

Comment: It would help if you include the code that calls the functions.  It also seems that you should look into local-scope of vars in Python- it does not matter what you call the parameter passed into the function, so you could call the var in the brackets "n" for every function, but it is preferable to give them a meaningful name that indicates what that parameter represents- just useful for others looking at the code, and good practice!  Lastly, using a docstring inside the function makes it very clear what the functions do, and may include a desc. of the params passed (type/class).

Comment: My function f will be the Fibonacci function, but the z variable is j and f dependent.

Comment: Func f is definitely not Fibonacci.  There are two ways to approach it- iteratively or recursively- I'd recommend looking at the iterative approach.  We are here to help with code -fix it, improve it, debug it- but not to write it for you.  Have a look at my answer below and I hope it will make sense- if not, post a comment and I will try to answer it.

Comment: I already have the function, I did not use it because I did not want the solution, I wanted tips, so I think I misunderstood the question. I'm sorry, I'll write better next time.

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
def z(j):
    for j in range(0,f(n-1)):
        return j*y(n) + j*f(n-1) + j*f(n)
```

Notice you say this takes something called `j` while your other functions take `n`.

Did you mean

```
def z(n):
    for j in range(0,f(n-1)):
        return j*y(n) + j*f(n-1) + j*f(n)
```

When you get an error check the line number it refers to. 
Also, consider giving your variables longers names - just single letters get easy to muddle up!

---

As pointed out by the comment, once this stops giving the error message it might not do what you want.
You first function loops and then returns:

```
def f(n):
    a = something
    for i in range(n):
        a = a + i
    return a
```

(I presume `something` is set to, er, something)
Your `z` function returns as soon as it gets into the loop: perhaps you just want to collect the results and return them?

```
def z(n):
    stuff = []
    for j in range(0,f(n-1)):
        stuff.append( j*y(n) + j*f(n-1) + j*f(n) )
    return stuff
```

Notice the return is further left - no longer indented inside the `for` loop.
In fact you could use a list comprehension then:

```
def z(n):
    return [j*y(n) + j*f(n-1) + j*f(n) for j in range(0,f(n-1))]
```

Comment: Your version still only returns the first value of the iteration, because you're still calling `return` inside a loop.

Comment: D'oh - indeed...I just fixed the first problem

Comment: This helped a lot.  I thought I should add in j, since the sum in n has already been set to f. Thank you. Really!

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with the snippet that you posted.

It would help if you include the code that calls the functions. It also seems that you should look into local-scope of vars in Python- it does not matter what you call the parameter passed into the function, so you could call the var in the brackets "n" for every function, but it is preferable to give them a meaningful name that indicates what that parameter represents- just useful for others looking at the code, and good practice!

Lastly, using a docstring inside the function makes it very clear what the functions do, and may include a desc. of the params passed (type/class).

```
def range_sum(n):  # instead of f- range_sum seems appropriate
    """
    Sums the range of numbers from 0 to n
    >>> range_sum(4)  # example data
    10
    """
    # no idea what a is meant to be, unless an accumulator to 
    # store the total, in which case it must be initialised
    accum = 0   
    for i in range(1, n+1):  #iterates from 1 to n
        accum = aaccum + i
    return a  # returns the total

def y(m, const):  # use a descriptive func name
    """
    Sums the range of numbers from 0 to m and adds const
    >>> y(4, 7)  # example data
    17
    """
    return range_sum(m) + const

def z(j, n, m):  # pass all the vars you need for the function so they have a value
    """
    Something descriptive
    >>> z(4, 2, 5)  # example data
    ?
    """
    total
    for j in range(0,f(n-1)):
        total += j*y(m) + j*f(n-1) + j*f(n)
    return total

print("First Func, ", range_sum(4))
print("Second Func, ", y(4, 7))
print("Third Func, ", z(4, 2, 5))
```

Note that the number of arguments passed to each function matches the number expected by the function.  It is possible to set defaults, but get the hang of getting this right first.

Not sure what the last function is meant to do, but as mentioned in the comment above, showing some code to illustrate how you call the code can be useful, as in the sample.

Comment: Thank you for your help and patience. I thought I should add in j, since the sum in n has already been set to f. It worked out right now and I can use it to integrate over the sphere. I will need these sums for a much more complicated function.

Comment: I think you may be confusing global and local variables.  If, in the main program - NOT inside a function-  you have set values for each of the variables, then they can be accessed from anywhere in the program and used in expressions.  Values passed in to functions have local scope and exist within that function only- once the function finishes, they cease to exist save for any values returned.  What is your ultimate goal?  IF it is to get something like the volume of a sphere, this should be explicit in your main question, and wouldn't require Fibonacci.  Interested to know objective.

Comment: btw, if you found the response above helpful, a little upvote is nice- it is the up arrow beside the response.  Ditto for other useful answers. Thanks.

Comment: The main question is to integrate over a sphere using Fibonacci to reduce errors because the distributtion of points became better with this intervals.